# SQL71561 Error on Schema compare after initial import from database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssdt, visual-studio-2012

I have created a new sql server project with SSDT 2012, then I went to import an existing database and it created all my scripts. After that I did a schema compare between the project and the database I just imported the objects from. And I got tons of errors, most of them SQL71561 "contains unresolved reverence to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refere to any of the following objects.....

Am I expecting too much from SSDT that after an import a schema compare shouldn't return any errors ?

Comment: This happens with 3 part naming (you need to add a reference in the database project to either a *.dacpac or *.dbproj file for the other database(s)), or with ambiguous object names (you need to resolve this by changing the code to be more specific e.g. `SELECT column_name` -> `SELECT object_name.column_name`)